# How I know my document's size inside MongoDB with the ruby driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

The limitation of one document in MongoDB is 4Mo. I have some documents really heavy with a lot of data.

How I know my document's size inside MongoDB with the ruby driver ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use BSON.serialize and find the length of the resulting byte buffer.  See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/BSON#BSON-Ruby for an example of using BSON.serialize.

Comment: So you can do it like this:     `BSON.serialize(database.collection(:collection_name).find_one(_id: BSON::ObjectId('4f8698bfc4eb9605a1000001'))).size`

Answer (score 28):

Or native
Object.bsonsize(db.Foo.findOne());

Comment: +1 ! Can even size up the attribute of the document : Object.bsonsize(db.customer.findOne({'name' : 'harry'}).address);

Comment: Moreover, you can check size of any object: `Object.bsonsize(ObjectId())`, `Object.bsonsize({ is_free: true })`.