# Get MongoDB object size through Ruby connector

Tags: ruby, mongodb, bson

How do I get the BSON document size of a MongoDB record using the Ruby connector?  For BSON::Document.new(some_hash), .size seems to return the number of keys for the document, .bson_size doesn't exist, and .data_size returns an error.

Comment: Hey, this might be a possible duplicate of [How I know my document's size inside MongoDB with the ruby driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532845/how-i-know-my-documents-size-inside-mongodb-with-the-ruby-driver). Could you take a look there and see if the answers there help you out?

Comment: That page suggests using BSON.serialize, but it doesn't seem to exist.  I think it may have been part of a previous version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of [Mongo's Ruby Driver 2.0](https://github.com/mongodb/bson-ruby/blob/1a682e22ec998a2ad652a2d680f2f1515ef867ad/CHANGELOG.md#200) release, `BSON.serialize` is removed. If you have a `BSON::Document`, you can transform it to a `BSON::ByteBuffer` by calling `to_bson`, and then get its size by calling `length` on that.

Example:

```
BSON::Document.new({a: 1}).to_bson.length
=> 12
```